# Line resistance >> line reactance or the other way around?

Tags: resistance, transmission-line, reactance, conductance

Grainger and Steven write in *Power Systems Analysis* that "in a well-designed and properly operated power transmission system... the line **susceptances** B<sub>ij</sub> are many times larger than the line **conductances** G<sub>ij</sub>" (where the subscripts i and j refer to nodes of the power system).

Given that susceptances and conductances are reciprocals of reactances and resistances (respectively), it seems that an equivalent statement to the Grainger/Stevenson quote might be "the line **reactances** are many times smaller than the line **resistances**"

Web searches, on the other hand, indicate that line reactance >> line resistance. How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Post an image of the book please.

Comment: At low frequency reactance of a wire goes to zero. At high frequency it goes to infinity. At some frequency it's going to cross over the resistance. Is this a 50/60 Hz system or the PDN of a GHz digital system? The latter will have tremendously more reactance than the former, at least to switching current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken in your foundational assumption:

> Given that susceptances and conductances are reciprocals of reactances and resistances (respectively)

This is not correct. You seem to be working from an intuition that \$Y = \frac{1}{Z} = \frac{1}{R + jX} \approx \frac{1}{R} - j\frac{1}{X}\$ whereas this is not correct. The correct relation is

$$ Y = \frac{1}{Z} = \frac{1}{R + jX} = \frac{R - jX}{R^2 + X^2} $$

So \$G = \frac{R}{R^2 + X^2}\$ and \$B = \frac{-X}{R^2 + X^2}\$ and the ratios \$\frac{X}{R} = -\frac{B}{G}\$.

Answer (score 2):

Without reference to the book in question I can only draw on what I know about transmission lines (whether power AC or otherwise). Susceptance (in the parlance of transmission lines) doesn't refer to series components; it refers to the capacitive reactance between the two wires. You wrote this: -

> *where the subscripts i and j refer to nodes of the power system*

And, I suspect, it means "across" the two wires of a power transmission system.

If the book were talking about resistance and reactance we would be talking about the series resistance and series inductive reactance of the conductors in a transmission line. But, we're not; we're talking about line capacitance and line galvanic leakage and, the only thing that loses power or decreases transmission efficiency is the galvanic leakage.

So, we want the galvanic leakage currents to be low compared to the capacitive reactance currents between the two wires. And this means that susceptance (the inverse of capacitive reactance), is expected to be much higher than conductance.

Comment: Andy thank you for the clarification that, in the parlance of transmission lines, susceptance refers to shunt susceptance.

Comment: The OP is correct that in the context of the book, i and j refer to nodes. The admittance matrix Y relates the node voltages to the injected currents at each node as I = Y V. This admittance model is the subject of Chapter 7 of the Grainger textbook. Y = G + jB where G and B are just the real and imaginary parts of the complex matrix Y. In other contexts, Y, G, and B might represent the shunt parameters of a branch, but in this particular chapter of this book that is not the case.